# How to use `clippy::disallowed_method` with methods inside the same crate

Tags: rust, lint, rust-clippy

I have some functions defined in my crate that I want to disallow the use of inside of the same, using `clippy::disallowed_methods`.

For example:

```rust
fn f() { ... }

fn g() {
    f(); // Warning
}
```

I've tried the following clippy.toml

```
disallowed-methods = [
  "crate::f"
]
```

But no warning shows up when I run `cargo clippy`.

I've also tried `f`, `my_crate::f` and `::my_crate::f`, where `my_crate` is the name of the crate both functions are defined in, but none of them work.

I've tried it with other methods in external crates, such as `std::vec::Vec::new` and a warning successfully shows up.

Is there any way to make `disallowed_methods` work without moving the methods to another crate?

Comment: Is your crate a binary, or library target?

Comment: A binary, but ideally it should work in either, I might move logic from this binary to it's own crate eventually.

Comment: Sure, I'm just speculating that a binary crate may not be addressable/named in quite the same way as a library crate, if at all.

Comment: I just tried it out and it seems a library also doesn't work. I created a library named `t`, but using `f`, `t::f`, `::t::f` or `crate::f` still doesn't work, so I assume it's a shared problem.

Comment: Github was down a few minutes ago, so I couldn't check, but apparently it's a known [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy/issues/7479). Although it's still not working, so I guess the answer is that it's not supported yet?